# Wired PC breaks wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a computer connected via a switch Zyxel switch and a power line adapter connected to a router, supplied by my Internet Service Provider (ISP). When the compuer is on, the wifi fails regularly. This means that the wireless devices are still connected, but opening websites and co is not working.

- I connected the affecting computer directly to the router - no help
- I changes the ISP, which means I have a different router - so I can exclude a problem with that
- I tried the computer running Ubuntu and Windows - the problem occurs with both

The computer which causes the problem has a ASRock H61M-S main board and I'm using the ethernet plug on the main board.

I have this problem already for quite a long time and no clue what is causing it or how to fix it. Can somebody point me out how to look for the cause and fix it?

[image]

Comment: When the WiFi clients are unable to open websites, can the PC? Also, during this time can the WiFi clients `ping` the router / PC?

Comment: Yes everything on the PC and other wired clients works perfectly well. I think to rember that pings to the router are also possible, probably also to destinations outside the LAN but I will have to test it, when it fails again.

Comment: Please post a diagram of your network, clearly identifying modern/router/switch/WiFi devices.

Comment: I added the diagram above. The network used to be IPv4 now it uses iPv4 and iPv6. Both setups caused the same problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem when a PC is downloading updates, Microsoft updates use some P2P mechanism that saturates any low-ish bandwidth network and effectively kills any other machines connection.  If that PC downloading updates?

Comment: I thought so too but the fact that it happens with Ubuntu and Windows lets   me doubt.

Comment: I found out that killing dnsmasq and nmbd on both ubuntu machines speeds the network up again. How could this be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Can you add a diagram of how the various devices are connected?

One possibility is that your ISP only supplies you one IP address, and this is taken through DHCP by your computer. Then the WiFi, which is NAT-capable, can no longer connect.

Possibly you can plug the PC through an Ethernet port on the WiFi AP, if it has one available.